# Casting date in Talend Data Integration

Tags: date, casting, bigdata, talend, data-integration

In a data flow from one table to another, I would like to cast a date.

The date leaves the source table as a string in this format: "2009-01-05 00:00:00:000 + 01:00".

I tried to convert this to a date using a tConvertType, but that is not allowed apparently.
My second option is to cast this string to a date using a formula in a tMap component.

At the moment I tried these formulas:

```
- TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row3.rafw_dz_begi);
- TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",row3.rafw_dz_begi);
- return TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",row3.rafw_dz_begi);
```

None of these worked. When inserting the result into the target-table (MySQL, InnoDB) a receive the error message that the date is not valid. The format of the target field is a MySQL Date field.

How can I cast the date to the desired format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talend offers you a nice way of handling date formats.
You can easily change the date format in the Schema editor tab at the `tMap` window.

It works for both `tMap` input and output flows.
I've added a picture for a better illustration.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> to cast this string to a date using a formula.... error message that
>   the date is not valid. The format of the target field is a MySQL Date
>   field.

What I understand from your question is, you want to insert a date into MySQL Date field.

But the method that you are using, returns the 'String' type.

```
TalendDate.formatDate(String pattern, Date date);    //formats a date into Date/Time string
```

So in that case, if your field is of 'Date' type.

```
TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",row3.rafw_dz_begi));
```