# Convert EST into IST in Talend

Tags: database, postgresql, talend

I have a table in which a column consist of date like this:

*2017-05-25 12:00:00.0*
in EST timezone.

I want to convert into IST timezone and put the data in another table.
(database here is POSTGRESQL). Is there anyway to do the above in Talend?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand this issue. Why would you convert a timestamp? Wouldn't it be more practical to choose the timezone you need in the view layer? The date is still the same... Although I recommend storing in UTC.

Comment: The thing is I am creating a process which needs data in IST and the data I have to use is in EST which is already present in database.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35653484/how-can-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-and-vice-versa-in-a-talend-job

Comment: you can also use a tJava component and write a custom method to do the time comnversion and pass it to next components by storing it in global or context variables